# Proc SQL running total

Tags: sas

I am building a process in SAS EG and came to a sticking point when I needed a running total.  This would be very easy to do in Excel but my table is 22M records long.  I have VBA experience but not Proc SQL.  Can someone show me how to do a running total of dollars by item?  The data is sorted by Market/Segment/Item/Month.

Thanks
Jeff

[MyData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rofdG.png)

Comment: instead of picture, if you can show your input(small sample) and output you want, then will easy for someone to help you

Comment: Is there a reason you need `Proc SQL`  instead of a `DATA` step ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hierarchy is Market / Segment / Item, and maybe from the question one can presume an Item is unique across all Markets and Segments.

A running total is easiest in a DATA Step.  You will want to use `first.` automatic variables that are prepared when the step has a `BY` statement.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by Market Segment Item Month; * add month to make sure incoming data is ordered timewise, if not an error will appear in the log;

  if first.Item then RunningDollars = 0;
  RunningDollars + Dollars;  * The + syntax here is a `SUM` statement that causes the RunningDollars variable to be automatically retaine, meaning the value is available for the next record.
run;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know SAS coding at all so I didn't even know to ask for a DATA step.  I just know a running total is not possible without code.  I'll try this out.

Comment: Can you explain want and have?  I cannot get this to run.

Comment: I got it to work!  How can I add some currency formatting with no decimals?

Comment: I figured that out too.  Thanks!!